# Javascript looping problem and converting nested objects into an array

Tags: javascript

In the below array I am trying to convert "reporting" object into an array of objects.
Below is how I am trying:

```
  const data = [{
    m_id: '61',
    reporting: {
     0: {
      report_cd: 'L',
      report_category: 'Light Vehicles'
     },
     1: {
      report_cd: 'M',
      report_category: 'Motorcycles'
     }
    }
   },
   {
    m_id: '62',
    reporting: {
     0: {
      report_cd: 'L',
      report_category: ' Extra Light Vehicles'
     },
     1: {
      report_cd: 'M',
      report_category: 'Bike'
     },
     2: {
      report_cd: 'H',
      report_category: 'Extra Heavy'
     }
    }
   }
  ];

  var arr = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
   let keys = Object.keys(data[j].reporting);

   for (var i = 0, n = keys.length; i < n; i++) {
    var key = keys[i];
    arr[key] = data[j].reporting[key];
   }
   data[j].reporting = arr;
  }
  console.log(data);
```

I am able to convert it into an array in the current output but there's some problem in my loop due to which for both the objects I am getting back 3 arrays for reporting:

Current Output :

```
[{
 "m_id": "61",
 "reporting": [{
  "report_cd": "L",
  "report_category": " Extra Light Vehicles"
 }, {
  "report_cd": "M",
  "report_category": "Bike"
 }, {
  "report_cd": "H",
  "report_category": "Extra Heavy"
 }]
}, {
 "m_id": "62",
 "reporting": [{
  "report_cd": "L",
  "report_category": " Extra Light Vehicles"
 }, {
  "report_cd": "M",
  "report_category": "Bike"
 }, {
  "report_cd": "H",
  "report_category": "Extra Heavy"
 }]
}]
```

Expected Output:

```
[{
 "m_id": "61",
 "reporting": [{
  "report_cd": "L",
  "report_category": "Light Vehicles"
 }, {
  "report_cd": "M",
  "report_category": "Motorcycles"
 }]
}, {
 "m_id": "62",
 "reporting": [{
  "report_cd": "L",
  "report_category": " Extra Light Vehicles"
 }, {
  "report_cd": "M",
  "report_category": "Bike"
 }, {
  "report_cd": "H",
  "report_category": "Extra Heavy"
 }]
}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that since arrays are reference types using the same array(`var arr`) for the second iteration will also modify the `reporting` array of the first object.

An alternative using `map` and `Object.values`:

```js
const data = [{
    m_id: '61',
    reporting: {
      0: {
        report_cd: 'L',
        report_category: 'Light Vehicles'
      },
      1: {
        report_cd: 'M',
        report_category: 'Motorcycles'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    m_id: '62',
    reporting: {
      0: {
        report_cd: 'L',
        report_category: ' Extra Light Vehicles'
      },
      1: {
        report_cd: 'M',
        report_category: 'Bike'
      },
      2: {
        report_cd: 'H',
        report_category: 'Extra Heavy'
      }
    }
  }
];

const result = data.map(el => ({...el, reporting: Object.values(el.reporting)}))

console.log(result)
```

`Object.values` is just like `Object.keys` but instead of returning an array of keys, it'll return an array of values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.keys to create your array for reports inside data object

```js
const data = [{
    m_id: '61',
    reporting: {
      0: {
        report_cd: 'L',
        report_category: 'Light Vehicles'
      },
      1: {
        report_cd: 'M',
        report_category: 'Motorcycles'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    m_id: '62',
    reporting: {
      0: {
        report_cd: 'L',
        report_category: ' Extra Light Vehicles'
      },
      1: {
        report_cd: 'M',
        report_category: 'Bike'
      },
      2: {
        report_cd: 'H',
        report_category: 'Extra Heavy'
      }
    }
  }
];

const result = data.map(x => ({
  ...x,
  reporting: Object.keys(x.reporting).map(key => x.reporting[key])
}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Why not `Object.keys(x.reporting).map(key => x.reporting[key])`?

Comment: applied the suggested change